# Can i generate a windows form from the code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I accidentally deleted some control and visual studio gave me an error warning that I ignored and now I lost my whole design.

The form.designer.cs, the code (.cs) still exist. only the form design is empty of all controls :( Can I undo this error?

Comment: Only the same way you'd revert any other change - Ctrl + Z, revert to previous commit etc.

Comment: No, it is gone.  That source control is important does have to be learned the hard way.

Comment: You should always use version control like git. It costs nothing and Visual Studio even asks you to create a new git repo every time you create a new project

Comment: You may be able to partially recover by finding the part in form.designer.cs that the designer doesn't like - are you getting any compiler errors when you build the project?

Comment: It's pretty messed up now, after i closed the project and reopened it. I'll just redesign the form ugh thanks guys and ctrl z didnt do it LOL

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the one to tell you this, but the form.designer.cs is the code that is used to generate the controls, their properties/settings, and place them on the form. When you drag and drop a control onto the form, VS auto generates the backing code for you. The warning you got was probibly saying something like 'You wont be able to undo this', i would try `Ctrl + Z` and see if you can undelete the file. Check your recycle bin, not sure if VS places it there, or try to get a file recovery tool.

Other than that, youre pretty much out of luck.